# Pair values individually using techniques like lapply

Tags: r, list, ggplot2

It is very handy to use `lapply` family for which I can compute many combination at the same time. However, I found myself still doing a lot of copy-paste with those values I wanted to assign individually rather than to compute all the combinations. Follows is an example, if I use `lapply` to this example, I will get all the combination of `1,2,3,4` and `0.2,0.7,1.2,1.7`. Is there any way I can simply pair `1-0.2;2-0.7;3-1.3;4-1.7` individually and use similar techniques like `lapply`?

```
title <- function (k){
  list(
  k [[1]] + ggtitle ('A = 0.2'),
  k [[2]] + ggtitle ('A = 0.7'),
  k [[3]] + ggtitle ('A = 1.2'),
  k [[4]] + ggtitle ('A = 1.7'))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the values into a title vector `tt` of same length of you plot list and use `lapply` over the `seq`uence.

```
tt <- c(0.2, 0.7, 1.2, 1.7)

res <- lapply(seq(k), function(i) {
  k[[i]] + ggtitle(paste0("A = ", tt[i]))
})
```

#### Result

First two results.

```
res[[1]]
```

[image]

```
res[[2]]
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(iris, aes(Petal.Length, Petal.Width)) + geom_point()
k <- list(p, p, p, p)
```

Answer (score 1):

Jay.sf's answer is also good, but I think it might be worth pointing out that the `mapply()` function was specifically designed to handle these parallel-vectors cases. In the example below, we use a custom anonymous function inside the apply to attach titles to a list of plots.

```r
library(ggplot2)

# Create list of plots
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point()
p <- rep(list(p), 4)

# Vector of titles
titles <- paste0("A = ", c(0.2, 0.7, 1.2, 1.7))

# Using the mapply function
out <- mapply(
  function(plot, title) { # <- function that does the work
    plot + ggtitle(title)
  }, 
  plot = p, title = titles, # <- arguments to function as vectors/lists
  SIMPLIFY = FALSE # <- we want list output
)

# Show plots
patchwork::wrap_plots(out)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-02-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for introducing how to use mapply in this circumstance!! It is really helpful!!